# Why is the content inside the invisible asp:PlaceHolder rendered?

Tags: asp.net, visibility, asp.net-4.5, asp.net-placeholder

Why is the content inside the placeholder rendered?
This code results in: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
For the MainGuard object!

How should one handle this situation?

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="<%# Model.MainGuard != null %>">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# Model.MainGuard.Image.RenderImage() %>" Height="50" />
    <%# Model.MainGuard.Name %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not rendered -- but it still has to be *parsed* by the runtime, hence you still get the exception.  Your only recourse is to check for null each time:

```
<asp:Image runat="server"
    ImageUrl="<%# Model.MainGuard == null ? "" : Model.MainGuard.Image.RenderImage() %>" />
<%# Model.MainGuard == null ? "" : Model.MainGuard.Name %>
```

You might consider using an extension method to allow for cleaner syntax:

```
public static string StringOrEmpty(this MyClass self, Func<MyClass, string> selector)
{
    if (self == null) return "";

    return selector(self);
}
```

Then you can write:

```
<asp:Image runat="server"
    ImageUrl="<%# Model.MainGuard.StringOrEmpty(mainGuard => mainGuard.Image.RenderImage()) %>" />
<%# Model.MainGuard.StringOrEmpty(mainGuard => mainGuard.Name) %>
```

Comment: Okay - I just find it odd that there isn't an even cleaner way.. But thanks - the extension method makes it acceptable..

Comment: I changed it to a generic: `public static string StringOrEmpty<T>(this T self, Func<T, string> selector) where T : new()`